# Downloading Images from Discord Message

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

How could i download all iamges in a discord messages but have a random name for them so i dont have 2 diffrent image.jpegs or image.png ??

Note:
I want to get the image from the message
and if they sent the image though a url than get the image from there message url

Please help
Thanks.

Comment: I think it might help you https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H3R27U7ac5Y

Comment: Not really at all im coding a bot

Answer (score 3):

It downloads all type of images/gifs see `image_extensions`.

Works with urls and sent images by chat.

You can choose in which path image should be saved - `images` in example.

```py
import discord
import os
import aiohttp

@client.event
async def on_message(message: discord.Message):
    if valid_image_url(message.content):
        await download_image(message.content, "images")

    for attachment in message.attachments:
        if valid_image_url(attachment.url):
            await attachment.save(os.path.join("images", attachment.filename))


def valid_image_url(url: str):
    image_extensions = ['png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif']
    for image_extension in image_extensions:
        if url.endswith('.' + image_extension):
            return True
    return False


async def download_image(url: str, images_path: str = ""):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url) as resp:
            if resp.status == 200:
                image_name = os.path.basename(url)
                with open(os.path.join(images_path, image_name), "wb") as f:
                    f.write(await resp.read())
```